# Wordpress: Problem with rest_cookie_invalid_nonce

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, wordpress-rest-api, nonce

When I send rest request to the wp-rest by:

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  // 'headers' => $headers,
  'httpversion' => '1.0',
  'sslverify' => false,
  'body' => json_encode( array(
    'data' => $field,
  ))
));
```

Unfortunately, I get 403 error:

```
{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"Kodem jednorazowy z ciasteczka jest nieprawid\u0142owy","data":{"status":403}}
```

Maybe someone knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you resolve? if yes please add the answer

Answer (score 1):

When you use `wp_remote_...` your cookies are not included. WordPress REST API uses the `_wpnonce` value to validate your session against the `wp_rest` keyword and your cookie values. To fix this, your options are to either switch to an AJAX browser call to the endpoint from the same browsing session, or you can stick with the remote REST API request and include your cookies in it like this:

```
$cookies = [];
foreach( $_COOKIE as $name => $value ) {
    $cookies[] = new WP_Http_Cookie(
        [ 'name' => $name, 'value' => $value ]
    );
}
$args = [
    'body' => [],
    'cookies' => $cookies,
    'headers' => [ 'Content-type' => 'application/json' ],
];
$url = get_rest_url() . 'endpoint/v1/endpoint/';
$response = wp_remote_get( $url, $args );
```